# Poll for only password change in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

what is the recommended approach for polling password changes only in Active Directory, get the updated password and update else where ?

I have looked into classes in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace like 'DirectoryNotificationControl' class but seems like this would poll for any attribute and later on we need to query to see if attribute we are interested (password) has indeed changed.

Also how do we get password value from active directory ? It is possible using LSA although very complex..

Comment: It is possible using LSA although very complex...

Answer (score 3):

The only "simple" way (and those are VERY big quotes around "simple") is to write up a [Password Filter Dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is hosted on the Domain Controller.

You can implement the [PasswordChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and have your code update whatever external thing that needed to be notified of the password change.

However this must be done in native code, so no C# allowed.

---

I originally went down this road and ended up giving up on it and used a different method of tracking the changed passwords, however one thing I did discover along the way was an open source project called [passwdhk](http://passwdhk.sourceforge.net/) that may be helpful for you.

What passwdhk does is it implements a Password Filter DLL for you, however all the filter does is launch another executable with the command line arguments that where passed in to the password change notify function ("post-change program" is forwarding the arguments from [PasswordChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "pre-change program" is forwarding the arguments from [PasswordFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). This allows you to still write your code that updates the other service in C#, it just takes the password in from the command line instead of intercepting the password itself.

Comment: +1 Right, I forgot this one. But it should be implemented on each Domain Controler or only on one with a particular role ?

Comment: @JPBlanc from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "*All domain controllers are writeable, therefore password filter packages must be present on all domain controllers.

**Windows NT 4.0 domains:**  Notification on domain accounts takes place only on the primary domain controller. In addition to the primary domain controller, the password filter packages should be installed on all backup domain controllers to allow notifications to continue in the event of server role changes.*"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, by default the password (stored in an encrypted way) cant't be read in Active-Directory. You can change the policy to store it in a reversible way, but it's really not a good thing.

The only way I know, is to install a componant on each client machine. The component catch the password change and you can do what you want.

From NT to XP this component was called GINA (DLL). Begining Vista this companent should be written using Credential Provider API.